# Asp.net Core with Cookie and JWT does NOT redirect cookie request to login page

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies, jwt

Recently upgraded my app to asp.net core 6 and having problem that cookie requests are not redirected to login page but status code 401 is returned.

```
public static class AddExternalAuthProvidersExtension
{
    public static void AddExternalAuthProviders(this IServiceCollection builder,
        IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        builder
             .AddAuthentication(options =>
             {
                 options.DefaultScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
                 options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
             })
            .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.IncludeErrorDetails = true;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidIssuer = FlymarkAppSettings.Instance.JwtTokenIssuer,
                    ValidAudience = FlymarkAppSettings.Instance.JwtTokenAudience,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(FlymarkAppSettings.Instance.JwtTokenSigningKey))
                };
            })
          
        builder.ConfigureApplicationCookie(config =>
                    {
                        config.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/LogIn";
                        config.AccessDeniedPath = "/Identity/Account/LogIn";
                        config.SlidingExpiration = true;
                        config.Events = new CustomCookieAuthenticationEvents();
                        config.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
                    });
        builder.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .AddAuthenticationSchemes(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme, JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
            });

    }

}

public class CustomCookieAuthenticationEvents : CookieAuthenticationEvents
{
    public override Task RedirectToLogin(RedirectContext<CookieAuthenticationOptions> context)
    {
        if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api") &&
            context.Response.StatusCode == StatusCodes.Status200OK)
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        else
        {
            return base.RedirectToLogin(context);
        }
    }

    public override Task RedirectToAccessDenied(RedirectContext<CookieAuthenticationOptions> context)
    {
        if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api") &&
            context.Response.StatusCode == StatusCodes.Status200OK)
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden;
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        else
        {
            return base.RedirectToAccessDenied(context);
        }
    }
}
```

I see that my events are hit and in response I am getting location to redirect but something rewriting status code to 401 from 302

[image: Response]

Comment: You have added a default policy for all requests that user must be authenticated. In your Login and AccessDenied actions you have to set `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute to allow non-authenticated user can view.

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos yes i set both to check cookie or jwt which is ok. Allow anonymous attribute is in places and it works however issue is that those endpoints which has to authorised need to be redirected to login.

Answer (score 0):

Seems I have found solution. Looking at code [JwtBearerHandler](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Security/Authentication/JwtBearer/src/JwtBearerHandler.cs#L230) to skip overriding status I can rewrite OnChallenge event and call handle event..

```
.AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
                {
                    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
                    {
                        OnChallenge = ctx =>
                        {
                            if(!ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api") && ctx.Response.StatusCode != (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)
                            {
                                ctx.HandleResponse(); //THIS solves my problem <----
                            }
                            return Task.CompletedTask;
                        }
                    };
              
                    options.IncludeErrorDetails = true;
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        ValidateLifetime = true,
                        ValidIssuer = FlymarkAppSettings.Instance.JwtTokenIssuer,
                        ValidAudience = FlymarkAppSettings.Instance.JwtTokenAudience,
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(FlymarkAppSettings.Instance.JwtTokenSigningKey))
                    };
                })
```

PS: will leave open question in case if someone provide better solution